# How to word-wrap a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Word wrap works well on long strings without any special characters. I'd like to use it on a URL. Rather than filling all the columns in a row, the text goes to the next row on encountering special characters like =, & etc. Is there some other method to solve this?
HTML:

```
<div style="word-wrap: break-word; width:100px;" id="foo"></div>
```

JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById("foo");
div.innerHTML = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello+world&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=aNqUVZ7ZK4KVuATI3IGIDg";
```

JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/areaeooc/1/).

PS: Overflow isn't very nice!

Comment: what should be your output?

Comment: And should it be cut and pastable?

Comment: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/css/aGVW190612-CSS-to-force-long-text-and-urls-to-wrap-on-all-browser.html

Comment: If you *didn't* need it to be cut-and-pasteable, you could insert zero-width spaces (U+200B, `\u200B` in JavaScript) in the string where you're happy for it to break. But they'll come with the string when copy-and-pasting, so...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `word-break: break-all;`

```js
var div = document.getElementById("foo");
div.innerHTML = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hello+world&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=aNqUVZ7ZK4KVuATI3IGIDg";
```

```css
#foo{
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;" id="foo">
    
</div>
```