# Wrap hyperlink text in navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks in advance for your help!  I have looked at several posts but wasn't able to find a solution that saved my problem or really addressed the issue I am facing. I am building a fixed navbar using bootstrap 3.3.5.  Some of hyperlink text is long.  I want to wrap the hyperlink text.  I will need to use dropdowns as well. I have been trying to wrap the text unsuccessfully.

I have tried creating my links in a `<p>` like this:

```
<li><div><p class="navber-text"><a href="#temp_url">a very long and wordy link goes here</a></p></div></li>
```

I have also tried adding:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-text {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    white-space:normal !important;
    max-width:200px;
    word-wrap: normal;
  }
```

to my custom.css file and I just can't seem to get it to work.

Would someone mind showing me where I am making my mistake?
Would a button group be a better option for me here?

I do need to use drop downs as I said earlier and if I did use a button group I would it to remain visible at the top of the screen at all times.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: This question is already answered 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177183/how-to-word-wrap-a-url/31177253#31177253

Answer (score 0):

Use `word-break: break-all;` to break the words in CSS